# How to filter xml elements based on the value of different element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I got this xml (the 'other' elements have different names, just skipped them for clarity):

```
<root>
<elements1>
<element>
<id>1</id>
<other>a</other>
<other>b</other>
<other>c</other>
</element>
<element><id>2</id>
<other>a</other>
<other>b</other>
<other>c</other>
</element>
<element><id>3</id>
<other>a</other>
<other>b</other>
<other>c</other>
</element>
</elements1>

<elements2>
<element>
<id2>1</id2>
<other2>a</other2>
<other2>b</other2>
<other2>c</other2>
</element>
<element>
<id2>2</id2>
<other2>a</other2>
<other2>b</other2>
<other2>c</other2>
</element>
<elements2>
</root>
```

I need to filter it so it shows something like this:

```
<root>
 <elements>
  <element>
   <id>1</id>
   <id2>1</id2>
   <other>a</other>
   <other>b</other>
   <other>c</other>
   <other2>a</other2>
   <other2>b</other2>
   <other2>c</other2>
  </element>
  <element>
   <id>2</id>
   <id2>2</id2>
   <other>a</other>
   <other>b</other>
   <other>c</other>
   <other2>a</other2>
   <other2>b</other2>
   <other2>c</other2>
  </element>
</elements>
</root>
```

So it should take the children of two different elements and put them together as one element filtering by the id and id2.

Not sure how to do it. I've tried two for-each elements to filter the xml but it wouldnt work.

Comment: It is a grouping problem. Can you use XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML? Then use `for-each-group select="//element" group-by="id, id2"`. With XSLT 1.0 read up on Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet using a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id2" match="elements2/element" use="id2"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <elements>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="elements1/element[key('id2', id)]"/>
    </elements>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elements1/element">
  <xsl:variable name="el2" select="key('id2', id)"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="id, $el2/id2, (., $el2)/(* except (id, id2))"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A similar approach with XSLT 1.0 is

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id2" match="elements2/element" use="id2"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <elements>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="elements1/element[key('id2', id)]"/>
    </elements>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elements1/element">
  <xsl:variable name="el2" select="key('id2', id)"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="id | $el2/id2 | *[not(self::id)] | $el2/*[not(self::id2)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works fine, however I don't quite get how? Could you explain a bit more on what you did?

Comment: First I define a key `<xsl:key name="id2" match="elements2/element" use="id2"/>` to allow me to access `elements2/element` efficiently by their id. Then in the template for the `root` I only process those `elements1/element` which have a corresponding `elements2/element`, using the key function to establish that. Then the template for `elements1/element` again uses the key function to select the cross-referenced `elements2/element`, to be able to output its child elements like `id2` and the other elements.

Comment: The other problem just came up, what do I do if I do not want to just copy everything but pick and choose which elements I want to display?

Comment: I've solved my other issue, it was a silly thing, sorry for bothering with that and once again thanks for you help :)